# Adding a filter to comments_template

Tags: filters, templates, comment-form

I'm trying to add a PureCSS class to the `<form>` tag in the default comments template, but the class isn't being added. Here's what I've done so far:

```
function pwp_comments_form_pure($output) {
    $output = preg_replace('/class="comment-form"/', 'class="comment-form pure-form"', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('comments_template', 'pwp_comments_form_pure');
```

I know the `preg_replace` approach works, because I did the same for the default search form and it worked without any problems:

```
function pwp_search_form_pure($output) {
    $output = preg_replace('/class="searchform"/', 'class="searchform pure-form"', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('get_search_form', 'pwp_search_form_pure');
```

I've triple-checked the class names and hyphenation, and they all match up.

I've also tried adding a priority parameter of 1 and 100 to the `comments_template` filter, but it didn't make a difference.

Is there an override somewhere in the WordPress defaults that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `comments_template` filter should return [an absolute filepath to the comments template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_template) - use `comment_form_defaults` and set the `class_form` argument:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', function ( $args ) {
    $args['class_form'] = 'my form classes';
    return $args;
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you. I hadn't fully appreciated that `comments_template` was actually for _templates_!

Answer (score 1):

The filter you are using is [about the template path](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_template), it doesn't do anything with the form output. The class you want to add doesn't need a filter. You can set it when you set the arguments for your call to [`comment_form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) in your template.

```
$comment_args        =  array (
  'id_form'         =>  'comment-form',
  'class_form'      =>  'comment-form pure-form',
  ....
  );
$comment_form ($comment_args);
```

Comment: An equally good solution, and the only reason I didn't accept it was because  I need a solution that sits in my theme's `functions.php` file, rather than in the template.